# bitcoind -reindex or delete blockchain start over

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

blockchain is on disk (139GB) but not complete. Had an error. What is faster?
Deleting the blockchain and start over with bitcoind -daemon or bitcoind -reindex.
What will be faster to get it up and running?

Comment: This question belongs to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Grzegorz Żur because you don't know the answer to it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. You should post things like this on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, I calculated how long it would take to reindex and decided to delete and start again.

Watching the logs, you can see how long it takes to reindex each `.dat` file. It would depende on the speed of your machine and the speed of your connection.